# Rails datetime hour steps

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application where a user will select a delivery date for an order from a list of available dates and time. I have two slots per day (12:00PM and 18:00PM) and I want the displayed date in the select date time field to be always 24hrs ahead of the current date time and showing the closet date and time for the next 3 days.

i.e if the time just before an order is placed is 17:00PM, the next available time should be 18:00PM the very next day.

At the moment I have a delivery_times column of datetime type with the following options in the view form

```
    <%= f.datetime_select :delivery_time, 
               :default => 24.hours.from_now, 
               :minute_step => 30,
               :discard_year => true%>
```

is it possible to add a start hour, end hour and use hour steps other than the default of one ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `12:0PM` or `12:00PM`? Do you have `18:00AM` or `18:00PM`? And what kind of time is `18:00AM`? By the way, if you display in 24 hours, then `AM` and `PM` are not supposed to be displayed.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, the delivery times available are 12Noon and 6PM daily. My problem is how to make the delivery date drop down always show these available times 24 hours ahead of the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work to create a list with available delivery times:

```
# Determine the next available delivery time, 12:00 or 18:00
now = DateTime.now
next_hours = [12] * 12 + [18] * 6 + [12] * 6
next_start_hour = next_hours[now.hour]

# The offset in hours for each next entry in the list
offset_hours = if next_start_hour == 12
  [6, 24, 30, 48]
else
  [18, 24, 42, 48]
end

# Create an array of DateTime elements
first_option = now.change(hour: next_start_hour)
delivery_times = [first_option]
offset_hours.each do |offset|
  delivery_times << first_option + offset.hours
end

p delivery_times
```

Not tested for all starting hours and timezone/daylight-saving issues, there might be some edge cases...

You can use the `delivery_times` array to create the `choices` parameter for a [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) or its cousin [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select).

```
<%= f.select :delivery_time, delivery_times.collect {|dt| [ dt.to_s(:long), dt.to_s(:db) ] } %>
```

This should render a select with the available delivery dates. The `to_s(:db)` format for the `id` part of the select should make saving it to the database a breeze (does it?). The displayed value can be tweaked at will.

The code to create the `delivery_times` array can be put in:

1. The controller. Not very good since it would not be reusable anywhere else in your application.
2. A helper method. Better idea, but now you are putting business logic in a view helper.
3. A method in the `Order` model that returns an array of available delivery times.
4. Somewhere else in your `app` directory where you store your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however I am not quite sure where to put it.

Comment: You could use it as a parameter for [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) and feed the result to `select`. I will add some details to the answer.